# PHP date not working with saved value timestamp

Tags: php

I am trying to convert a timestamp using `php` date like this...

```
update_option('last_lookup', time());
$last_lookup = get_option('last_lookup');

$timestamp1 = date("c", $last_lookup);
$timestamp2 = date("c" , 1549133279);

echo $last_lookup;
echo $timestamp1;
echo $timestamp2;
```

Only `$timestamp2` is returning the correct result, if I echo `$last_lookup` then I get the correct timestamp back.

Could it be that `$last_lookup` is a string and date needs an integer?

Can anyone suggest a fix?

**UPDATE**

Doing a var_dump on $last_lookup gives me...

```
string(10) "1549133279"
```

Comment: The results depend entirely on what `$last_lookup` contains and what time zone you've set...

Comment: Where does `last_lookup` get assigned? If it is a string you would need to use strtotime();

Comment: where is your last_lookup

Comment: $last_lookup comes from a wordpress options. If I echo it out then it does show the correct timestamp 1549133279

Comment: Have updated the post with the source of $last_lookup. WordPress must do something to the timestamp when it stored it

Comment: If you're unsure of what `$last_lookup` contains then just print it (e.g. `var_dump($last_lookup);`).

Comment: var_dump show string(10) "1549133279"

Comment: I literally cannot get it to break outside of wordpress lol, using time() or even a string with `1549133279` in it works for me, i dont have wordpress around to test it on though.

Comment: So it looks like it is a WordPress issue then, it is storing the timestamp as a string instead of an integer

Comment: You can cast to integer to see if that helps: `$timestamp1 = date("c", (int)$last_lookup);`

Comment: PHP is loosely typed and [your code](https://3v4l.org/qNsL1) does not seen to exhibit any strange behaviour. The error must be somewhere else. All we know so far is that it doesn't work and it isn't correct but that's not a lot of info...

Answer (score 1):

Your timestamp string is a unix timestamp from [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php)

You can convert it to timestamp format with the [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function.

For example, passing your string of

`1549133279`

to

`$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $t);`

yields `2019-02-02 18:47:59`

Edit:

Just as an update, I took your code and placed it in the index.php file of `wp-content/themes/twentynineteen/index.php` (the theme I was using to test) out of curiosity and had zero issue with it. I added a break at the end of each echo and was able to see the following:

```
1549137644
2019-02-02T20:00:44+00:00
2019-02-02T18:47:59+00:00
```

Of course, the times are different because one was determined at runtime and the other is absolute so I am fairly certain that there isn't any issue with the code you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This method is working fine and tested, try this way and if you still face issue, debug your code with other functions

```
$last_lookup = time();

$timestamp1 = date("c", 1549133279);
$timestamp2 = date("c", "1549133279");
$timestamp3 = date("c", $last_lookup);

echo $last_lookup;
echo "<br>";
echo $timestamp1;
echo "<br>";
echo $timestamp2;
echo "<br>";
echo $timestamp3;
```

Comment: If I do var_dump on $last_lookup in your code then it shows int(1549135983) - If I do it on mine then it does string(10) "1549133279"

Comment: The date method can handle string value and int value

Comment: I am lost then, must be WordPress doing something funky to the values

Comment: Yeah you might find them out